# Google Mobile Ads SDK was not show for Interstitial?

Tags: android

I was take for 3 days to migrate from Google Admob SDK to Google Mobile Ads SDK, the Banner it's show as usual but only the Interstitial doesn't show, Do i missing something in my bellow bellow:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobExtras;

public class interstitial_Ads extends Activity {
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "85735d538e4e4bd0";
private InterstitialAd interstitial;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ads_full);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("color_bg", "AAAAFF");
    bundle.putString("color_bg_top", "FFFFFF");
    bundle.putString("color_border", "FFFFFF");
    bundle.putString("color_link", "000080");
    bundle.putString("color_text", "808080");
    bundle.putString("color_url", "008000");
    AdMobExtras extras = new AdMobExtras(bundle);

    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    // Create ad request.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true)
    .addNetworkExtras(extras)
    .build();
    // Begin loading your interstitial.
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
}

// Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an interstitial.
  public void displayInterstitial()
      {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded())
        {
      interstitial.show();
    }
  }
}
```

Only the Interstitial Ads doesn't show but Banner Ads show as usual.
Anybody here can explain me based on my code above?

Thank you very much.